# Create hierarchical object in c#

Tags: c#, object, logic

I have a sample data as shown below which can vary at runtime(Rows and columns can be added or removed):

```
Column1   Column2  Column3
RED       Car      100
RED       Car      150
RED       Bike     140
BLUE      Car      240
BLUE      Bike     120
```

My class is as below:

```
 public class Data{
       public List<Data> ChildObjects;
       public string strName;
    }
```

I want to create object of above sample data as below:

- parentObj will contain 2 ChildObjects-RED and BLUE and strName as
  "parent"
- RED obj will contain 2 ChildObjects CAR and BIKE  and    strName as
  "RED"
- BLUE obj will contain 2 ChildObjects CAR and BIKE    and strName as
  "BLUE"
- Each CAR object will contain 5 ChildObjects    (100,150,140,240,120)
  and strName as "CAR"
- Each BIKE object will    contain 5 ChildObjects (100,150,140,240,120)
  and strName as "BIKE"

so the structure will look like this

```
                100
                150
       Car  --  140
                240
               120
RED---
               100
               150
      Bike --  140
               240
               120


                100
                150
       Car  --  140
      |         240
      |         120
BLUE---
      |        100
      |        150
      Bike --  140
               240
               120
```

Please help me to write efficient and dynamic code snippet for the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var parentObj = new Data
            {
                strName = "parent",
                ChildObjects = new List<Data>
                {
                    // Creation of RED
                    new Data
                    {
                        strName = "RED",
                        ChildObjects = new List<Data>
                        {
                            // Creation of Car
                            new Data
                            {
                                strName = "Car",
                                ChildObjects = new List<Data>
                                {
                                    new Data {strName = "100"},
                                    new Data {strName = "150"},
                                    new Data {strName = "140"},
                                    new Data {strName = "240"},
                                    new Data {strName = "120"}
                                }
                            },
                            // Creation of Bike
                            new Data
                            {
                                strName = "Bike",
                                ChildObjects = new List<Data>
                                {
                                    new Data {strName = "100"},
                                    new Data {strName = "150"},
                                    new Data {strName = "140"},
                                    new Data {strName = "240"},
                                    new Data {strName = "120"}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    // Creation of BLUE
                    new Data
                    {
                        strName = "BLUE",
                        ChildObjects = new List<Data>
                        {
                            // Creation of Car
                            new Data
                            {
                                strName = "Car",
                                ChildObjects = new List<Data>
                                {
                                    new Data {strName = "100"},
                                    new Data {strName = "150"},
                                    new Data {strName = "140"},
                                    new Data {strName = "240"},
                                    new Data {strName = "120"}
                                }
                            },
                            // Creation of Bike
                            new Data
                            {
                                strName = "Bike",
                                ChildObjects = new List<Data>
                                {
                                    new Data {strName = "100"},
                                    new Data {strName = "150"},
                                    new Data {strName = "140"},
                                    new Data {strName = "240"},
                                    new Data {strName = "120"}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I need dynamic logic for the sample. I do not know the columns and rows and data inside the sample. It is given at runtime.

Comment: I don't understand the logic how is this table transformed into a tree

Comment: Hello, I want exact same thing like the code you gave. But at runtime I don't know the sample data will contain how many rows and and what values. So the object should be created dynamically.